# Gostaria de saber como posso subistituir dominios para o meu newsletter?

Tags: php, javascript

Por gentileza, queria saber como seria os codigos desse sistema simples
gostaria de colocar uma lista de emails com diversos servidores ex: @gmail.com @aol.com @outlook.com

e em cima eu colocaria @hotmail.com
e a lista que ficaria em baixo seria subistituido tudo que tivesse depois do @  por > hotmail.com

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="inicial" id="inicial" placeholder="@hotmail.com">
<br />
<br />
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#000000">
            <td height="10" colspan="2"><span class="texto">Lista de emails</span>
             
          </tr>
          <tr align="right">
            <td height="136" colspan="2" valign="top"><br>
              <textarea name="emails" style="width:100%" rows="8" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="form" id="emails"></textarea>
              <span class="alerta">Click > </span> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="26" align="right" valign="top" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="enviar" value="Substituir"></td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: Seu exemplo está sem dados... coloque dados de como está atualmente e de como você quer que fique.

Comment: so fiz isso, nao sei fazer mais dai pra frente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o que você quer é "adicionar um sufixo por linha", independe de ser qualquer dado a ser inserido.

Para inserir um sufixo/prefixo basta pegar o valor atual, então "somar" a string o dado a ser inserido. No caso do `textarea` você deve quebrar por linha. Para simplificar, já que estou familiarizado, irei usar JQuery.

Para quebrar por linha utilize `.split('\n')` e faça um `loop`:

```
  $.each($('textarea').val().split('\n'), function(index, data){

  });
```

Então faça também um array com os resultados, além disso você disse requer remover outros provedores (ou seja remover tudo após  `@`) use `.split('@')[0]` e então some o sufixo desejado:

```
value.push(data.split('@')[0] + sufixo);
```

Agora você possui uma array `value` com todos os dados com sufixo, basta agora unir todo a array e coloca-la numa `textarea`, use o `.join("\n")` para isso.

```
$('textarea').val(value.join("\n"));
```

### Resultado

```js
$('#enviar').on('click', function() {
  
  // Array dos resultados:
  var value = [];
  // String do sufixo (a ser inserido):
  var sufixo = $('#inicial').val();
  
  // Executa função em cada linha:
  $.each($('textarea').val().split('\n'), function(index, data){
    // Se tiver algo escrito remove o sufixo (se já existir!) e adiciona o sufixo:
    if(data.trim() !== ""){
      value.push(data.trim().split('@')[0] + sufixo);  
    }
  });

  // Junta a array inserindo quebra de linhas entre eles
  $('textarea').val(value.join("\n"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="inicial" id="inicial" value="@hotmail.com" placeholder="@hotmail.com">
<br />
<br />
<tr align="center" bgcolor="#000000">
  <td height="10" colspan="2"><span class="texto">Lista de emails</span>

</tr>
<tr align="right">
  <td height="136" colspan="2" valign="top">
    <br>
<textarea name="emails" style="width:100%" rows="8" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="form" id="emails">
teste@aol.com
teste2@gmail.com
xxxxx@hotmail.com
yyyyy@provedor.com
meuemail
</textarea>
    <span class="alerta">Click > </span> 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="26" align="right" valign="top" colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="enviar" value="Substituir">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: no caso, como eu colocaria esse codigo no meu html? eu coloquei <script type="text/javascript">

$('#enviar').on('click', function() {
  .....

nao deu certo :/

Comment: Você deve carregar o JQuery (insira exatamente a primeira linha que está no HTML) antes de tudo.

Comment: se não for muito incomodo teria como postar pra mim no pastebin.com ? não estou conseguindo >/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/P6qtjEdz coloquei aqui como coloquei e nao esta funcionando

Comment: Acredito que a ordem esteja errada. O `Javascript` não tem como prever os elementos sem que eles existam quando é chamado. Por isso você deve colocar o `<script>` após todos os elementos já serem exibidos. Coloque o `<script>` no final da página, acima apenas do `</html>`. Acredito que isso será suficiente: http://pastebin.com/d2pYVeSy

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela atenção amigo !